# Clarifications on YAML syntax and Ruby parsing

Tags: ruby, parsing, yaml

I am new to YAML and Ruby. I am using the following Ruby code to parse a YAML file:

```
obj = YAML::load_file('test.yml')
```

Are the following YAML file contents for 'test.yml' valid?

Case 1:

```
test
```

In this case, I don't specify the value of `test` (something like `test : true`) but my Ruby parsing code does not throw an error. I thought this was an invalid YAML syntax.

Case 2:

```
:test : true
```

In this case, the Ruby code treats `test` as a symbol instead of a string and when I do `puts obj[:test]`, it returns the result to be "true". Is this a Ruby thing? Other languages will interpret it as a string `":test"`?

Case 3:

```
:test : true
:test : false
```

In this case, instead of throwing up an error for redefinition of `:test`, my Ruby code takes the latest value for `:test` (which is `false`). Why is this? Does YAML syntax allow for re-definition of elements and in which case only the latest value gets taken?

Comment: You'd benefit from reading http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html. Also, we need to see a better example of your YAML being parsed, in situ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1:** YAML allows [unquoted scalars](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788859), or "bare" strings not enclosed in quotes. Compared to quoted strings they are less flexible, since you can't use certain characters without creating ambiguous syntax, but the Ruby parser does support them.

```
1.9.3-p448 > YAML::parse('test').to_ruby
=> "test"
```

**Case 2:** As you've guessed, this is Ruby-specific since YAML has no concept of "symbols". When converting a YAML [mapping](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//) to a Ruby hash, scalar keys that start with a colon are interpreted as symbols instead of strings.

**Case 3:** Under YAML's definition of a [mapping](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//), keys must be unique, so a strict parser should throw an error when given your example. It seems the Ruby parser is more lenient, and allows the same key to be defined multiple times with a last-value-wins rule. This is also allowed in native Ruby hashes.

```
1.9.3-p448 > YAML::parse("test: true\ntest: false").to_ruby
=> {"test"=>false}
1.9.3-p448 > { 'test' => true, 'test' => false }
=> {"test"=>false}
```

Comment: Thanks Grantovich for your time and reply. In Case 1, I see that the contents are deserialized as a String rather than a Hash. I was under the impression that YAML::load_file returns a Hash all the time. Also, what is the purpose of unquoted scalars? In Case 1, I thought Ruby would have an unquoted scalar like "test" parsed automatically to be true and put in the Hash.

Comment: And another question which may not necessarily related to this topic. I am trying to come up with a design where in I will have an base options file that has some values for some options and have override files that if needed will change those options. In essence, I am exploiting the non strictness of the Ruby parser mentioned in Case 3. Please let me know if it is a good design?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, `YAML::load_file` simply returns a Ruby representation of a YAML document. A YAML document can contain any combination of arrays, hashes, and strings -- there is no rule that says it must be a single hash. If this is new to you, the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) provides a decent overview of how YAML documents work.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, you would not actually be exploiting the non-strictness of the Ruby parser in this case. Keys must only be unique within a single hash -- since your "base" and "override" are completely separate YAML documents, there are no duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks Grantovich. Regarding your reply to second comment, even if I include a YAML from another YAML(not sure if I can do that), it is going to be different hashes?

Comment: There is no "include" mechanism for YAML. Before going further, I would highly recommend reading the resource that the Tin Man posted to get a better overview of YAML and how it can be used with Ruby.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36060/discussion-between-venk-k-and-grantovich)

Answer (score 2):

A great way to learn how the YAML parser converts to/from Ruby structures, is to write Ruby code that outputs YAML, and look at what it's doing:

Here's a basic hash:

```
require 'yaml'
foo = {'test' => true} # => {"test"=>true}
foo.to_yaml # => "---\ntest: true\n"
```

A hash using a symbol as a key:

```
foo = {test: true}
foo.to_yaml # => "---\n:test: true\n"
```

A hash with conflicting keys, causing the first to be stomped-on by the last:

```
foo = {test: true, test: false}
foo # => {:test=>false}
foo.to_yaml # => "---\n:test: false\n"
```

YAML is creating the hash, but hashes can't have duplicated keys; If they do, the collision results in the second replacing the first.

"[Yaml Cookbook
at the YamlForRuby site](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html)" is also a great resource.